# Java CompareTo method states I cannot convert int to boolean even though neither is used

Tags: java, interface, comparable, compareto

```
public int compareTo(Person p) {
    int res = 1;
    String personStr = p.getId();
    String thisId = this.getId();

    if(thisId.equals(personStr)){
        res = 0;
    }
    else if(thisId.compareTo(personStr)){
        res = -1;
    }

    return res;
}
```

A quite simple compareTo method I have implemented but I don't get the error message. The condition in the else if statemint gives me a message saying that it can't convert from int to boolean. I get that, but the thing is that I'm using netiher. I just want to compare 2 simple strings, why does this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you should notice is that the interface 'compareTo' is returning an int  'public int compareTo' being the sign

if statements rely on a boolean value, however you use thisId.compareTo(personStr) which will return an integer, just like the method you are creating.

Your first if statement is fine - 'equals' returns a boolean. However the second does not, it will likely return either a -1, a 0 or a 1.

Comment: Ah, now I get it...*palmslap. Been a long day. I just set thisId.compareTo(personStr) == -1){...
and it worked fine.

Comment: We all have them, don't stress.

Comment: @Baxtex it would be better to use `thisId.compareTo(personStr) < 0` - in theory compareTo could return something else than -1, 0 or 1 - say -5 for example.

Answer (score 2):

> but the thing is that I'm using netiher

Are you sure about that?

This results in an `int`:

```
thisId.compareTo(personStr)
```

But you're using it as a `Boolean`:

```
if (yourResult)
```

An `if` statement requires a boolean, it can't just be used on any value.  For example, consider the difference between this:

```
if (value == 1)
```

and this:

```
if (value)
```

In some languages you can get away with that.  Some languages assign degrees of "truthiness" to all types, allowing you to use them in boolean expressions.  Java is not one of them.  You have to explicitly define your boolean logic in Java:

```
if(thisId.compareTo(personStr) > 0) // or whatever your logic should be
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to compare those 2 strings why not use

```
public int compareTo(Person p) {
  String personStr = p.getId();
  String thisId = this.getId();
  return thisId.compareTo(personStr);
}
```